# addEventListener is not working when on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi i am trying to use addEventlistener on an event firing.But it is not working.
When i click on header_search button it works fine and log on console "clicked" and a window opens . On the opened window there is a close button which id is "search-close" . and when i press on the button that does not work.Even it does not console log "clicked". Could anyone help? Is that a browser problem?

```
var search = document.getElementById('header_search');
var close = document.getElementById('search-close');

console.log(search);
console.log(close);

search.addEventListener('click', function(event){
    console.log("clicked");
    event.preventDefault();
    showFullScreen();
    document.getElementById('search-top').focus();
});

close.addEventListener('click', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log("clicked");
    searchClose();
});

function showFullScreen(){
    $('html').prepend('<div class="full-screen-search" />');
    var search_form = document.getElementById('search-header-form').innerHTML;
    $(".full-screen-search").html(search_form);
    $(".full-screen-search").fadeIn(1000);
};

function searchClose(){
    $(".full-screen-search").fadeOut(200);
    $(".full-screen-search").remove();

};
```

Comment: If you are using jQuery, don't use `addEventListener` and `getElementById`. That kind of defeats the "more with less" benefits of jQuery :)

Comment: why are you using jquery only partly?!

Comment: Possibly, your id-mistake, can you post your HTML too?

Comment: google jquery bind events on dynamically created elements or event delegation.. have fun doing this without jquery

Comment: Is the `search-close` button appended using JS after the page has loaded?

Comment: Go into console of your new opened window and check whether script is there or not. If not then include it on that page.

Comment: As I mention below. *If* you can also post your page HTML (from browser, not source code), then I can add a better example of how to write this *using* jQuery. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using jQuery, don't use `addEventListener` and `getElementById`. That kind of defeats the "more with less" benefits of jQuery. Use `.click(function(){...})` or `.on('click', function(){...})` and `$('#idname')`

You are adding your window dynamically, so the close button is not the one you originally found with `getElementById('search-close')`.

Use a jQuery *delegated event handler* attached to a non-changing ancestor  element

e.g.

```
 $(document).on('click', '#search-close', function(){...
```

You cannot have duplicate IDs on a page, or only the first can be found. Suggest you change to using classes instead:

```
 $(document).on('click', '.search-close', function(){...
```

Delegated events work by listening for events (e.g. click) to bubble up to a non-changing ancestor element. `document` is the best default of nothing else is closer. It then applies the jQuery selector at event time, so the target does not need to exist when the code was registered.

***If you can also provide your page HTML, I will provide a full example of how to better write your code with jQuery*** :)

Comment: I thought this must be the case, but OP is writing the `close` button to the console, so if this was the case I'd have hoped they'd spotted it themselves.

Comment: @Rory McCrossan: I am assuming the original is also in the page and they are appending a copy (or moving it) for the popup.

Comment: That would also make sense. +1